# Fiddler2 for tcp only

Tags: tcp, fiddler

hoping you could help out... is there a way of getting Fiddler2 to monitor just tcp traffic as opposed to looking for HTTP?

I have a legacy application that sends TCP text and need to capture it to track an issue.. Fiddler2 is great for web based http monitoring and if possible i'd like to use this for TCP based monitoring as well (I understand the layout & format) .. is this possible or do I need to look at WireShark or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As explained on the Fiddler website, Fiddler is a HTTP/HTTPS proxy server. You cannot debug TCP with it; use Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark for those tasks.

Comment: Successor is Microsoft Message Analyzer:
[MMA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/messageanalyzer/)